# How do I use geometry object in processing.runalg()

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, clip

I am trying to clip a polygon (large road network) with every row in another polygon (district polygon) using PYQGIS.

```
layer_adm_level = QgsVectorLayer(base_path + adm_level + ".shp",'adm_level','ogr')
if not layer_adm_level.isValid():
    print "Layer failed to load!"
for adm_level_feature in layer_adm_level.getFeatures():
    ID = adm_level_feature["ID"]
    try:
        processing.runalg("qgis:clip",adm_level_feature.geometry(),road_network,base_path + "clip_network_" + str(ID).replace(".",""))
    except Exception, e:
        print e
```

The problem is when I supply the adm_level_feature.geometry() parameter to the clipping function. I get an error `Error: Wrong parameter value: <qgis.core.QgsGeometry object at 0x7f98a6311938>`. 
This means it expects a shapefile, any work around where I can give it an object instead?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to iterate over your layer using the **Clip** function, you need to select each polygon first before applying the algorithm. Try running the following:

```
layer_adm_level = QgsVectorLayer(base_path + adm_level + ".shp",'adm_level','ogr')
if not layer_adm_level.isValid():
    print "Layer failed to load!"
for adm_level_feature in layer_adm_level.getFeatures():
    ID = adm_level_feature["ID"]
    # Line below selects each feature before running algorithm
    layer_adm_level.setSelectedFeatures([adm_level_feature.id()])
    try:
        # Input is the layer
        processing.runalg("qgis:clip",layer_adm_level,road_network,base_path + "clip_network_" + str(ID).replace(".",""))
    except Exception, e:
        print e
```